# Saving and retrieving multiple objects using boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization

How can I use boost serialization to save and get multiple objects (number of objects varies)?
For example I have class Contact, and I input contact and save it to file. Another time I input another contact, and it should also be saved in file.

I think the save function should be like this:

```
void save_contact(const Contact &s, const char * filename){
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::app);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << s;
    ofs << "\n";
}
```

And to retrieve the contacts I should keep track of contacts number, am I right?
To retrieve single contact I use the following code:

```
void retrieve_contact(Contact &s, const char * filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> s;
}
```

Here is how serialization function inside Contact class looks like:

```
template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & m_CompanyName;
        ar & m_FirstName;
        ar & m_LastName;
        ar & m_PhoneNumbers;
    }
```

(m_CompanyName, m_FirstName and m_LastName are std::string, m_PhoneNumbers is std::vector)
So is there way somehow to retrieve contacts without keeping track of number of contacts? Or can you suggest me another way to save and retrieve contacts, saved at different time? Also how can I edit the saved file to modify Contact?

Comment: 1 question at a time. You don't "edit" an archive. You write a new archive.

Comment: @sehe Thank you for the answer. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, use the predefined serialization for standard containers. So, e.g.

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
```

And then

```
void retrieve_contact(std::vector<Contact>& s, const char * filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> s;
}
```